# What to do on Sukuot if there is no sukkah?

Tags: sukkot

Sometimes it happens that it is not possible to either build a sukkah or find one due to the absence of a nearby synagogue. What is the way out of this situation?

Comment: Netillas Lulav is the least of your worries!

Comment: relevant: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/38937/11501 - https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/99364/11501

Comment: Well you will for sure have to eat. But there are certain types of things that are less problematic to eat outside the sukkah (snacks, shehakol, etc) - so maybe you could just eat that. Though you'd have an interesting problem with the seduos - you are chayiv to have 2 seudos each day with challah, grape juice/wine, etc - so mistama you'd have to have that even though you didn't have a sukkah.

Comment: Netilas lulav is generally done in shul...

Comment: אונס רחמנא פטריה

Comment: There is a minhag to shake the lulav after reciting the bracha **in the Sukkah** before praying Shacharit and then additionally to shake the Lulav during Hallel (without repeating the beracha. See [here](https://halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Order_of_Taking_the_Four_Minim)

Comment: Wait for it to rain